# Why Android gives issues with tel attribute href="tel:8665487349"?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am trying to use this `href="tel:8665487349"` in a Web application which is responsive, when the page is on mobile, iOS works properly but on Android I am getting an issue, the pop-up is not present. It goes directly to dial the number.

This is the whole component

```
        <a href="tel:8665487349" style="text-decoration:none">
            <p class="apply-phone">
                <img src="assets/images/icon-phone-b.png">Or call to apply by phone
            </p>
        </a>
```

By pop-up I mean: pop-up is the one when you click on a phone number in your screen so the OS ask you if you really want to call or no? its like: `Call | Cancel` that is the one that is not showing up.

This is what appears when you click on the phone number:

[image]

PS: I added the JavaScript tag to the question because there could be possible solutions using JavaScript.

Comment: What is the content of the popup

Comment: @Alok the pop-up is the one when you click on a phone number in your screen so the OS ask you if you really want to call or no? is like: `Call | Cancel` that is the one that is not showing up.

Comment: That's just what Android browsers do, more or less. On 6.0 my phone goes to a phone app screen that offers options to call, save as contact, or send SMS.

Comment: @Pointy so you say that clicking in the phone number in the screen, it will automatically call and that is a regular behavior on Android phones now?

Comment: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/click-to-call-links-mobile-browsers  it may vary with browser

Comment: So either you implement you on way to do this or may need to accept it same

Comment: @Alok this means that not showing the pop-up and doing the call without asking for confirmation, its a regular behavior?

Comment: I've never seen an android device that would immediately start dialing, but there could be some phones/browsers that do. Exactly what browser and version of Android are you working with?

Comment: As i told it vary device to device browser to browser like  Many other html features.

Comment: Also You can make your custom solution for same,it will be the right way as it will help you to build your website reputation.

Comment: @Alok see the picture added to the question. Thats what I see.